# Python how to iterate from an array of objects and use key values to update multiple records at once

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, loops, iteration

Python how to iterate from an array of objects  and use key values to update multiple records at once. I wanted to 
update multiple rows in the table where companyid = company and applicant_id = applicant as you can see company and applicant value in the json and set attached_document_ins.is_viewed equal to the checked value based on the task id. https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEEPV.jpg (table rows)

## code

```
def post(self, request):
    data = request.data
    print("Response Data :" , data)
    try:

         for item in data['tasklist']:
            company = item['company']
            applicant = item['applicant']
            hey = item['checked']

        attached_document_ins = DocumentTask.objects.filter(company=company , applicant = applicant)
        for attached_document_ins in attached_document_ins:
            attached_document_ins.is_viewed = True
        attached_document_ins.save()
        return Response("Success", status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    except DocumentTask.DoesNotExist:
        return Response("Failed.", status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

## data

```
{
   'tasklist':[
        {
            'company':6,
            'checked':True,
            'files':[

            ],
            'applicant':159,
            'id':35,
            'task':'s'
        },
        {
            'company':6,
            'checked':True,
            'files':[

            ],
            'applicant':159,
            'id':36,
            'task':'ss'
        },
        {
            'company':6,
            'checked':True,
            'files':[

            ],
            'applicant':159,
            'id':37,
            'task':'sss'
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Which fields do you want to update ? And on what condition ?

Answer (score 0):

You can you queryset.update to update multiple rows

```
DocumentTask.objects.filter(company=company , applicant = applicant).update(is_viewed=True)
```